# application of Lowenheim-Skolem theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

So if minimal model of ZF exists, it is said that it is countable set by Lowenheim-Skolem. So, is Lowenheim-Skolem saying that for any countable theory with existence of infinite model there exists standard model, respecting normal element relation, that is countable infinite?

Answer (score 2):

No. The existence of standard models is strictly stronger.

It is consistent that there are no standard models, to see this note that the standard models are well-founded, in the sense that there is no infinite decreasing chain of standard models such that $M_{n+1}\in M_n$, simply because $\in$ itself is well-founded and standard models *use* the real $\in$ for their membership relation.

So there is a minimal standard model. But this model has the standard $\omega$ for its integers, so it cannot possible satisfy $\lnot\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$, so it must have a model of $\sf ZFC$ inside, but this model cannot be standard.

**See also:** [Transitive ${\sf ZFC}$ model](http://cantorsattic.info/Transitive_ZFC_model#Minimal_transitive_model_of_ZFC) on Cantor's Attic.

Comment: OK, then how can L be minimal and standard both?

Comment: @user81182: $L$ is minimal among class models that contain all the ordinals. The minimal standard model does not contain all the ordinals and is of the form $L_\alpha$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$.

Comment: @user61182: I'm not sure I understand your question. If there is a standard model then there is a minimal one. Since every model has an inner model which satisfies $V=L$, if $M$ is a minimal standard model then $L^M$ is a minimal standard model which satisfies $V=L$. Since $V=L$ is absolute we have that $L^M$ is actually $L_\eta$ (of the "real $L$") for some $\eta$, and this is the least transitive model in the sense of inclusion as well, not only in the sense of membership.

Comment: @Carl: You might want to post a more elaborated answer, I am just leaving for office hours and won't have time to do this for a couple of hours. :-)

Comment: @CarlMummert Oh got that part. I was mistaken.

Comment: That is a nice argument.